# Can TFS Source Control (TFVC) be used for Drupal website development?

Tags: php, svn, drupal, version-control, tfs

It appears so far that the Drupal community prefers Git and seems to have conventional workflows related to development that depend on Git.

We are using TFS 2013 which can host Git repositories, but we have been working to standardize use of TFVC for source control and would need to restructure our TFS governance to support a small fraction of the development community that is developing a Drupal site (for example, we have a single team project model).

The team using Drupal cited the typical development workflow for Drupal would be interrupted if they use TFVC, and they asked me how they would accomplish [an example work scenario](http://artfulrobot.com/how-I-use-git-for-my-drupal-sites) using TFVC instead of Git.

They also like the [use of sub-trees in Git](http://getlevelten.com/blog/tom-mccracken/smarter-drupal-projects-projects-management-git-subtree) because it enables them to more easily merge updates from the Drupal community with changes they made to certain modules.  Apparently, they perform this frequently.

Is the Drupal development life-cycle dependent on Git these days? If we host Drupal source using a TFVC instead of a Git repository, what would be the risk? Is there anyone developing [greenfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenfield_project) Drupal sites using TFVC as a source control repository in an enterprise team setting? If so, ***can you please share how you made it work well for you (or how it doesn't) and how you organize work for your team***?

I am trying to find a solution everyone can be satisfied with and I could really use your help because I don't know Drupal!

Answer (score 0):

Sure Drupal with TFS works just fine, but the workflow would be different. They can use the `tf.exe` commandline to grab sources from source control and if they want to they can still grab the main drupal sources from git and commit those to TFS.

But if this works really well for the team, why not make use of the features TFS 2013 offers and let them use whatever works best for the team. From a server admin position, why would you want to force them to use something other, while the tool supports both formats for a reason.

Comment: Hi @jessehouwing - I noticed your blog today - very nice info. I'm glad you saw this.  I'm seeking more detail that will help us communicate a solution.   From a source control server admin perspective, I agree. Work management, reporting, test cases and build are also a focus and all other teams are in a a single team project that is using TFVC.  If there was the ability to link work items and create build definitions across heterogeneous team projects using git with multiple repositories, then going with Git for them would be an easier decision for us.

Comment: Link work items is possible. Build across repositories too, but Team Build has no support for SubModules out-of the box. The build workflow can be customized to invoke the `git.exe` commandline to fetch the submodules. The fact that Single Team Project can't currently use both TFVC and Git repositories can only be solved by placing work in the central Team Project and the sources in a separate team project in the same collection.